# Google Search Console verification fails on single site while many others had no issue

Tags: google-api, dns, verification, google-apis-explorer, google-search-console

<sup>Interestingly, this is apparently the [official](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support) way to reach **Google API support**?  (...akin to Microsoft/SO's [documentation partnership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/stackoverflow-documentation-for-microsoft-developers)?)  Interesting — but obviously this limits the private information that I can include in my "support request"...</sup>

---

I have added-then-verified 400+ domains (with each of their `http`/`https`/`www`/`no-www` variations, for 800+ total) on **Google Search Console** via the related API's, without issue.

One domain is giving me a problem with verification via 'HTML File Upload', even though it's triple-checked to be set-up the same as the other 825 that verified without issue.

I compared WHOIS and [intodns.com](https://intodns.com) DNS Health report and I also [cleared the DNS Cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache) and waiting a couple days to see if it was a caching issue.

> [image: img]

I've tried multiple verification methods, but this error persists on both the `http://` and `http://www.` versions of the one site. The site itself works fine and I can't see any anomalies with it on my end.

---

I'm not sure if this could be related but the webmaster's [site list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/webmasters.sites.list), does include one strange property that is apparently verified (*in addition* to the two unverified versions of the problem domain):

> [image: img2]
>             <sup>(I've masked the ID number since I have no idea what it represents.)</sup>

---

How can I get my ownership of this site verified on Google Search Console?

Comment: To the close-voter: how can this be off topic if I was specifically directed to post here with the [tag:google-apis-explorer.] tag, due to Google+SO's support partnership?

Comment: Problem "solved itself" mysteriously after sending Google Feedback complaining about how tough it is to get support...  Deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify your site ownership by the alternate method. By inserting HTML tag you can verify your ownership easily. From search console you will get the HTML Tag. The Other way is to verify the ownership is Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics.

HTML Tag Sample is: `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="String_we_ask_for">`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Thanks for the answer, although I did mention in the question that I have also tried multiple verification methods. I have no issue with multiple methods on several hundred other site variations that I've verified in this batch. I suspect something must be anomalous in the back-end.  (I won't down-vote since you just joined, but others might.)

Comment: I'm closing/deleting my question since the problem "solved itself" but might as well accept the only answer.... A for Effort.  (I can't remember if you'd still get credit)